# $\int_0^{x_0} e^xf(x)= {{23\over 12}} $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Let $f$ be a real function with $f(0)=0 ,$ differentiable for $x \neq0 $ and $f'(x)= \frac{e^x}{3f^2(x)+2f(x)+1}$. There also exists a $x_0, 0<x_0<2 $ s.t. $f(x_0)=1$

---

I’ve already shown that $f^3(x)+f^2(x)+f(x)=e^x-1$ from multiplying the given fraction with the denominator and intergrating. Also I have shown that $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$ with $f'(0)=1$.

---

I am asked to prove that $\int_0^{x_0} e^xf(x)= {{23\over 12}} $

---

I have tried substituting $e^x$ and/or $f(x)$ in various different ways but Im still unable to solve it . If anyone can help me I would really appreciate it!

---

EDIT

I tried submitting $f(x) = u $ then $dx= {du\over f'(x)}$ an the limits become $0$ and $1$ $\int_0^{1}(u^4+u^3+u^2+u)f'(x) du  $ but there is still that $f'(x)$ that I cannot get rid of and cannot use it in any beneficial way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there: from what is given we have \begin{align*}
\int_0^{x_0} e^x f(x) \: dx &= \int_0^{x_0} \left(3 f(x)^3 + 2f(x)^2 + f(x) \right)f'(x) \: dx \\
&= \frac{3}{4} \cdot f(x_0)^4 + \frac{2}{3} \cdot f(x_0)^3 + \frac{1}{2} \cdot f(x_0)^2 - \left( \frac{3}{4} \cdot f(0)^4 + \frac{2}{3} \cdot f(0)^3 + \frac{1}{2} \cdot f(0)^2 \right) \\
&= \frac{3}{4} + \frac{2}{3} + \frac{1}{2} = \frac{23}{12}. \end{align*}

Edit: remark that I forgot to mention something important. Since $f(x)$ is differentiable for $x > 0$ and by the given expression for $f'(x)$ (note that $3a^2 + 2a + 1 > 0$ for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$!) we have that $f$ is monotone so that we can indeed apply the substitution rule without any issues!

Edit2: the above remark (Edit) is not needed! Integration is too long ago for me. The integral follows straight from the fundamental theorem of calculus as $$x \mapsto \frac{3}{4} \cdot f(x)^4 + \frac{2}{3} \cdot f(x)^3 + \frac{1}{2} \cdot f(x)^2$$ is an antiderivative of the continuous function that we are integrating.

Comment: really don't want to be annoying but I dont really understand how we went from the first integral to the second , why is $e^xf(x) = (3f^3(x)+2f^2(x)+f(x))f'(x) ? If you can enlighten me with that please . @Neckverse

Comment: @AntonyTheo Sure, it follows from the given expression for $f'(x)$, by bringing the denominator to the other side and multiplying both sides by $f(x)$. Do you see it?

Comment: Damn, that's really smart I am really happy you helped me . cheers!

Comment: @AntonyTheo No problem, happy to have been of help :)

Comment: @AntonyTheo See [separation of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables)